# error al conectar base mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

ya hice la misma pregunta pero lamentablemente no tuve una respuesta util, intente conectar a a una base mysql usando php, el codigo es el siguiente

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','phpmysql');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo 'no se pudo conectar a la base de datos '.mysqli_connect_error();
      exit();
}
```

al probar el codigo me tira el siguiente error, unknown database 'phpmysql', el nombre de la base de datos esta bien escrita, cree varias con distintos nombres por si generaran alguna confusion pero siempre el mismo error obtengo, alguien sabe porque.

Comment: Si accedes con tu usuario `root` y haces un `SHOW DATABASES`, ¿si te es visible dicha base de datos?

Comment: me fije tanto desde la consola mysql de wamp y si aparece, tambien aparece si la busco en phpmyadmin, estoy seguro que el error no es porque el codigo este mal escrito

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asi

```js
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Nombre del host
$usuario="root";  // Usuario de la base de datos
$contraseña="";  // Contraseña de la base de datos
$basedatos="PON EL NOMBRE DE TU BD"; // Nombre de la base de datos

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$contraseña,$basedatos) or die("Fallo la Conexion"); // Se establece la conexion

///lo siguiente es realizar la consulta que desees EJEMPLO
$consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM departamento");

?>
```

Comment: lo intente asi tambien pero tampoco, por alguna razon me da un error que dice no se reconoce la base de datos 'x' y pase todos los parametros correctamente, y cuando entro al mysql console de wamp e intento a acceder a la base de datos 'x' si accede.

Answer (score 0):

bueno me resolvieron la duda en otro lado, si alguien le surge este error usando wamp, luego de usar este codigo

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','phpmysql');
```

dependiendo de si crearon la base usando mysql o mariadb hay que establecer el puerto, por defecto viene el port 3306 que es el de mariadb, si usaron mysql
hay que especificar el port 3308 de tal manera que quedaria asi

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','subasededatos','3308');
```

el resto del codigo esta bien despues